# Magnific Popup not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, magnific-popup

Magnific popup seems to be working fine on desktop AND even Android phone but on an iPhone it shows the messsage **"A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded"** and doesn't play the Vimeo video.

**update: Just tried it on Chrome on my iPhone and it works fine. Looks like it's just Safari?**

**This is the HTML code:**

```
<ul id="page1-slider7" class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <div class="c c1"><a href="http://vimeo.com/80951188" target="_blank" class="portfolio-link video">Watch Video</a><img src="images/sidecar/video/SmuinXXmas.jpg" /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="c c2"><a href="http://vimeo.com/119386830" target="_blank" class="portfolio-link video">Watch Video</a><img src="images/sidecar/video/SunrunBrilliant.jpg" /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="c c3"><a href="http://vimeo.com/151719496" target="_blank" class="portfolio-link video">Watch Video</a><img src="images/sidecar/video/PIER_BOGO_Video.jpg" /></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The js file**

```
var initPopup = function(){
    $('.portfolio-link.video').magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 400,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: true
    });
}
```

Anyone have this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

Remove this attributes "disableOn: 400"

Keep only below code.

```
jQuery('.portfolio-link.video').magnificPopup({
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,
    fixedContentPos: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue like you. I think issue is not in coding.

There are lots of reason for facing such type of issue.

Try to follow below Procedure.
Trial 1)

```
1-Close all open apps by double pressing the Home button then swipe up on all open apps.

2-Clear your browser’s history and web site data by going to Settings > Safari > Clear History and Website Data.

3-Restart your device.

4-Reset your iPad or iPhone by  pressing and holding the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons at the same time for about 5-10 seconds until you see the Apple logo.
```

Trial 2)

> Method 1: Resetting Network Setting.
>
> Most of the time there is a network issue so we will start with
>   Resetting network settings. So to do so, Just Navigate to Settings >
>   General > Reset Network Settings.
>
> Method 2: Clear Browser Cache & History.
>
> If you figure out that Your network is not the issue, then your next
>   step is to fix issues with your browser. So better you Clear your
>   Browser Cache & History.
>
> In Safari go to Settings > Safari > Clear Website Data. Now close the
>   Browser and restart it to check whether the error still persists.
>
> Tip: Close all the unused tabs in your browser.
>
> Method 3: Resetting your iPAD
>
> Most of the time 2 methods mentioned above should work to Fix A
>   Problem Occurred with this Webpage so it was Reloaded error but if you
>   still can't get rid of it, then You need to Reset your iPad.
>
> Press and keep holding Home and Sleep Button for about 15 Seconds. Let
>   it Reboot on its own. This should fix any further issues. if not then
>   Try Method 4.
>
> Method 4: Reinstalling JAVA
>
> Finally, uninstall and then reinstall JAVA again. If Java is the
>   issue then this Method will fix this error for you.

And 3 rd try)

Read the solution in Apple's Forums and try Solution as said by Users in Thread.

> [A problem occurred with this web page so it was reloaded](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6707626?tstart=0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that didn't solve the issue. I tried it on Chrome on my iPhone and it works just fine. It may just be Safari?

Comment: I have solved my issue 2 times  with above techniques.

Comment: how do I reinstall Java on the iphone? I tried the other 3 methods but no luck.