# Magnific Popup doesn't work on mobile phones

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup which works fine on desktop browsers and tablets but when I click the image to open the light box on a mobile phone it goes to the video on the vimeo website instead of playing in the browser as it does with other devices. The odd thing is that I tested using an iPhone 4s and this is where the problem is occurring however it was also tested using a Samsung mobile and it worked correctly on that. I have a jquery.magnific-popup.js file so I wondered if there was some setting that I need to change in there.

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but, based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52058436/10850490), you gotta keep the parameters you know well like,

```
jQuery('.portfolio-link.video').magnificPopup({
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,
    fixedContentPos: true
});
```

Wish you also shared your source code and I hope you already solved the problem since it's been 1 year passed since the question asked.

Comment: Can you test it?

Comment: Tested on Iphone X, Galaxy S5 and Pixel 2 and the result is positive.